# detect changes in google drive list returning 0 but for same pagetoken returns change list with api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

Creating Java app that will capture Google Drive changes and using the Java client for the Google Drive V3 API. The code below shows how we are calling the Changes.List method to return a list of drive changes.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list following this for page token 3411 gives list

```
    {
    "kind": "drive#changeList",
    "newStartPageToken": "3420",
    "changes": [
    {
    "kind": "drive#change",
    "type": "file",
    "time": "2017-06-11T10:23:44.740Z",
    "removed": false,
    "fileId": "0B5nxCVMvw6oHaGNXZnlIb1I1OEE",
    "file": {
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "id": "0B5nxCVMvw6oHaGNXZnlIb1I1OEE",
    "name": "NewsLetters",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
   }
   },
   {
  "kind": "drive#change",
  "type": "file",
  "time": "2017-06-11T10:23:49.982Z",
  "removed": false,
  "fileId": "0B5nxCVMvw6oHeWdTYzlsOWpFOEU",
  "file": {
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": "0B5nxCVMvw6oHeWdTYzlsOWpFOEU",
  "name": "Copy of Copy of learning11.txt",
  "mimeType": "text/plain"
 }
 },
```

But by using code

```
      AppIdentityCredential credential= new  
   AppIdentityCredential(Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA));
        driveService = new Drive.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT_REQUEST, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
 String pageToken = "3411";
 while (pageToken != null) {
 ChangeList changes = driveService.changes().list(pageToken)
        .execute();
  Log.info("changes.getChanges 3411 "+changes.getChanges().size());

 for (Change change : changes.getChanges()) {
    // Process change
    System.out.println("Change found for file: " + change.getFileId());
 }
if (changes.getNewStartPageToken() != null) {
    // Last page, save this token for the next polling interval
    savedStartPageToken = changes.getNewStartPageToken();
}
pageToken = changes.getNextPageToken(); 
}
```

It gives

```
      Log.info("changes.getChanges 3411 "+changes.getChanges().size());
```

size returns 0
even I tried with

```
     driveService.changes().list("3411"). setFields("changes").execute()
```

same result 0
I am using AppEngine Google cloud server.
I would like to get a list of changes in folderID. 
What mistake I  am doing.Any pointers. Please help.

Is this because 
[Google Drive API through Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691677/google-drive-api-through-google-app-engine?rq=1)

Service Accounts are not supported by the Drive SDK due to its security model.
App Identity isn't working with the Drive API. Wouldn't it be a bug

But with AppIdentity I am able to read files in folder

```
   result = service.files().list().setQ("'" + locdriveFolderID + "' in 
   parents")
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, 
   name,description,mimeType,modifiedTime)")
                .setOrderBy("modifiedTime")
                .execute();
```

why changes.getChanges() returns  0 it should return list of changes which shows by api >1.

Please let me correct.

Comment: How to get changes list from serviceAccount by  AppIdentityCredential

Answer (score 0):

the result of changes.getChanges()  return list if

```
   AuthorizationCodeFlow authFlow = initializeFlow();
   Credential credential = authFlow.loadCredential(getUserId(req));
   driveService = new Drive.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT_REQUEST, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();

    ChangeList changes = mService.changes().list("3411").execute();
        Log.info("changes.getChanges "+changes.getChanges().size() );
```

Log output

changes.getChanges 10